# Redirect a image URL request to another without changing the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

After the vulnerability audit on my site, I found a wrong image having an extension like `ABC.php.jpg`
I have renamed it to `ABC.jpg`
Now the problem is, around 100k mails already sent and we keep the log (by saving the whole content in DB) of the mail and provide whenever required to a higher authority (By trigger mail with content which is in DB).

So I can't go in every mail and change the URL. What I want is, to access the URL (ABC.jpg) with URL `ABC.php.jpg`.
I have implemented some rules with htaccess file but they are simply redirecting the URL, and with this, image in mails will not load.

Comment: Could you post some of your relevant .htaccess rules?

Comment: Redirect 302 /ABC.php.jpg /ABC.jpg
This will redirect the URL which is a different aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per **jeprubio's** answer, I have found that we generally use this htaccess rule.

```
 RewriteRule ^ABC.php.jpg $1/images/ABC.jpg [R=301,L]
```

in which R uses for Redirect and L is for to stop further processing the ruleset, So basically if we remove **R** rule from rule, it won't redirect to new URL. 
Instead of it, it will serve response from new URL while hitting the old URL, So the final rule will be like this.

```
RewriteRule ^ABC.php.jpg $1/images/ABC.jpg [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have the redirect flag in your mod_rewrite rules [R].

As in:

```
RewriteRule ^ABC.php.jpg $1/ABC.jpg [R=301,L]
```

Just drop that flag and it should load the content without the redirection.

```
RewriteRule ^ABC.php.jpg $1/ABC.jpg [L]
```

Comment: Worked.
I am making like this : RewriteRule ^ABC.php.jpg $1/ABC.jpg [L]

It won't hurt any other URL right?

Comment: yes, it only affects the url which matches the `^ABC.php.jpg` pattern. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

If you want the script to load image, you can do in your ABC.jpg.php:

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("path/to/abc.jpg");
```

Note that you can't use the extension .jpg, if you want the server to execute your script. So it should end with .php

So in your image tag you could use this as URL:

```
<img src="http://host/ABC.jpg.php" />
```

Hope that helps